# wss сокеты с https Не работает

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ratchet

Для сервера использую php ratchet

```
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8000
);

$server->run();
```

на js подключаюсь

```
conn = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8000");
```

Без ssl с ws все работало хорошо.
Теперь не дает подключиться.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979793/php-ratchet-websocket-ssl-connect

Comment: Крч, просто в итоге настроил в ratchet свой сертификат. Не менял ничего в файлах серва.